# Получение координат для списка адресов

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

У меня есть большой список примерно на 10000 адресов в одном городе. Скажите пожалуйста как я смогу получить координаты для всех этих адресов и сохранить их, например, в csv?

Comment: Вероятно, как описано тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/

Comment: Обратите внимание на "Условия использования API Яндекс.Карт" https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage/?from=geocoder#conditions

Answer (score 1):

Или [тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding-docpage/).

Распарсить CSV, выдрать адреса, геокодировать их.

Важный момент: геокодировать адреса можно только на клиенте/сервере в момент запроса с клиента для показа на карте, условия использования запрещают разово геокодировать адреса и сохранить координаты себе. Разрешено только временное кеширование.